Recommendations on moral philosophy
I am a complete beginner to philosophy, but I would like to understand certain topics and I would appreciate it if you give me recommendations about what to read. Nowadays, I am mostly interested in morality philosophy, individualism, modern philosophy, and social philosophy. Can you recommend me classical philosphers and modern day philosophers. Thank you in advance.

https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/weber/

If you are a complete beginner, it is often good to start out on the edges of what are considered "serious" philosophical works.
Note contemporary philosophy is focused on physicalism, and the challenges that consciousness provide to that worldview. An excellent introductory book to thinking about consciousness is The Mind's I, by Dennett and Hofstadter. It is a series of science fiction short stories which raise philosophical issues, which the two authors then discuss.  It is the most fun serious philosophical book I have ever read, and I strongly recommend it.
Another introductory book that deals with the boundary between philosophy and the social sciences is The Worldly Philosophers, by Heilbroner.  The book discusses the thinkers whose views eventually led to the creation of economics as a science field, and is very relevant to your social science/philosophy interests.
A good starting point for moral thinking might be three diverse books: Situational Ethics by Fletcher to see how to apply utilitarianism to life, The Case for Animal Rights by Regan to see a rights based ethic thought thru, and the Earthseed novels by Octavia Butler to see a communitarian and Deep Ecology ethic integrated into living.
My own favorite philosopher is Karl Popper, who I discovered after I realized how important it is to understand epistemology:  how we know what we think we know. A basic intro to Popper can be found in his autobiography, An Unfinished Quest. A deeper sampling can be found in his essay collection Conjectures and Refutations.
These are only a sampling, and to really be able to think thru things like morality, society, and individualism one needs to dig into multiple alternative thinkers, and alternative perspectives/approaches.  But this sampling would get you started.

To questions like this I recommend The Story of Philosophy by Will Durant. Published a century ago in 1926, the book still holds up very well for philosophers up to that time.
And good luck to you. Happy and thoughtful reading!

If you want to understand something, you should start in the same way IT started. So start from the beggining. The term philosophy was coined by Pythagoras; you could start some years prior though. The 4 pillars of philosophy are : Anaximandros (: It exists-Υπάρχειν), Heraclitus (: It is becomming of-Γίγνεσθαι), Pythagoras (: It looks like-Φαίνεσθαι) and Parmenidis (: It is-Είναι).
